# Is there a way to tell which device a file is located on?

Tags: files, mount

If I have a file `/abc/def/ghi/jkl`, is there a way to tell which device it is located on, or should I parse `/etc/mtab` and see what matches `/abc/def/ghi/jkl` better?

Comment: Is there some particular use-case you have in mind for this, or just generally?

Comment: @ilkkachu I want to be able to find it in /abc/.zfs/snapshot/my-snapshot/def/ghi/jkl

Answer (score 36):

df will tell you device name and mount point, and ls will tell you device numbering:

```
paul $ pwd
/home/paul/SandBox/Toys/hSort
paul $ ls -l ReadMe
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul 296 Jan  8  2020 ReadMe

paul $ df ReadMe
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda9      103818480 3796556  94725184   4% /home

paul $ ls -l /dev/sda9
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 9 Jul 12 12:10 /dev/sda9
```

Comment: Device file numbers aren't very important nowadays.

Comment: @user253751 Agreed: but a couple of other answers showed more complex methods that found the numbers, so it was a simple extension, in case it mattered. Going direct from the relative filename (even a soft link), to both the device and the mount point, is the joy.

Comment: Bonus points, this works on mac, even when there's weird apfs nonsense going on.

Comment: "df ." note the dot.

Comment: @user62612 The OP specifically asked about a file. `.` is merely the current directory. A soft-link is followed, unless the target is not mounted. Weirdly, though, a named pipe hangs `df`.

Comment: "df ./filename" shows current xdev.

Answer (score 30):

If on Linux, you can run `findmnt` ([manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/findmnt)) on the path of the file:

```
findmnt -T /abc/def/ghi/jkl
```

Since the output is not meant to be parsable, if you want to read the result of a column (in this case SOURCE) into a variable you could do:

```
source=$(findmnt -rno SOURCE -T /abc/def/ghi/jkl)
```

(beware `$source` may not always be the path to a block device file like in the cases of network or fuse file systems, tmpfs, etc.).

Comment: instead of `-T` use `--target`. it is more self documenting.

Answer (score 10):

There are several, but it depends on what tools you can use. Are you on a shell, are you writing a script or program? In what language?

The [`stat()` function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) will return a device identifier for the file specified.

So will the `stat(1)` command. You could maybe use `stat -c %D filename` in a script. For example:

```
stat -c %D /mnt/persistent/test
```

will give, "0821". That means device 8, minor 33 ("21" is 33 in hex). So I can look into `/dev` what device has numbers 8, 33:

```
ls -l /dev | grep " 8, *33 "
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,  33 Jun 28 19:08 sdc1
```

Otherwise, yes, use `realpath` and match with mtab. In the same example:

```
REALPATH="$( realpath /mnt/persistent/test )"
df | grep ^/ | tr -s " " \
| while read row; do 
    PREFIX=$( echo "$row" | cut -f 6 -d " " )
    if ( echo "$REALPATH" | grep ^$PREFIX > /dev/null ); then
        echo "$row" | cut -f 1 -d " "
    fi
 done | sort | tail -n 1
```

Will output:

```
 /dev/sdc1
```

Although, as @Freddy pointed out, this whole script comes in a very poor second after `df`'s own syntax:

```
df --output=source /mnt/persistent/test | tail -n1
```

Comment: How would someone map the device identifier to a device?

Comment: @roaima the device identifier is made up of the major and minor device numbers, so on my system for example a file on USB disk /dev/sdc1 has a dev_id of 0821 (major 8, minor 33, that's 21 hex)

Comment: Is your script doing what `df --output=source /mnt/persistent/test | tail -n1` does?

Comment: @Freddy ...it totally is! I wasn't aware of this particular usage of `df`.

Comment: Instead of parsing mtab (which might not even be there or might be out of date), you can also take the major/minor pair from `stat()` and look the device up under `/sys/dev/block/<major>:<minor>`. However, note that it only works on Linux and doesn't work for non-device-backed mounts (FUSE, network filesystems, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

If on a GNU system, you could use `df` as:

```
$ df --output=source ~/.bashrc | sed 1d
/dev/sda1
```

Answer (score 1):

`stat` is your friend here. The "device" field will tell you what device your file is on. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309882/device-number-in-stat-command-output) for more info on how to interpret the device field.